# How to show an attribute in a table in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Simple question, in my xslt I want to print in a table the fixed value of an attribute, I obtain the same result if I put it in a label, but I want to do it well? Can anybody tell me how? Thnks.
In my doc.xml
 `<unit_price currency="$"> 4.00 </unit_price>`

In my doc.xslt

```
 <table>
 <xsl:for-each select="TotalProducts/products">
 <tr>
 <td>
    <xsl:value-of select="unit_price"/>
    <label> $ </label>
 </td>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to display the `currency` attribute in your table?

Comment: @MatthewGreen Yes, please. Without the label...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display an attribute from your XML you would use the xpath selector of `@`. So you can change your `label` line to the below.

```
<xsl:value-of select="unit_price/@currency" />
```